# Getting an AmazonKinesisException Status Code: 502 when using LocalStack from Java

Tags: java, amazon-kinesis, localstack

I'm writing integration tests using LocalStack to mock out my calls to Kinesis.  I've created a Kinesis client, but when I try to put records on Kinesis I get an error:

`com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.AmazonKinesisException: null (Service: AmazonKinesis; Status Code: 502; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)`

I've tried disabling CBOR and cert checking with the following:

```
System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.DISABLE_CERT_CHECKING_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "false");
```

System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.AWS_CBOR_DISABLE_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");

I build the client this way:

```
.withEndpointConfiguration(localstack.getEndpointConfiguration(LocalStackContainer.Service.KINESIS))
.withCredentials(localstack.getDefaultCredentialsProvider())
.build()
```

I get a 502 every time.  Everything works fine for S3, it's just the Kinesis service that's giving me trouble.   Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: The following post describe how to set up a kinesis+dynamoDB test env: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60190352/9361998

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had a similar issue while connecting Kinesis over localstack locally. I was using the v2 SDK java library.

**Root cause**

By default, kinesalite doesn't support CBOR and should be disabled to make it run. Internet is flooded with flags to disable CBOR but none of them worked for me.

You have to do two things:

1. Set environment var `AWS_CBOR_DISABLE=true` to tell **localstack** to stop using
2. Set environment var `aws.cborEnabled=false` to tell **AWS SDK** to stop using it.

In my case, I was stuck with the SDK flag which is referred in `software.amazon.awssdk.core.SdkSystemSetting`

Comment: However, bumping to "software.amazon.awssdk" % "kinesis" % "2.20.115" fixes the issue for me, so this workaround may not be needed anymore