# CBORFactory NoClassDefFoundError exception in spark 3.0.0

Tags: java, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

I am having spark streaming application using kinesis and running in EMR 6.0.0,
It's running fine locally but when deploying  to AWS EMR it keeps failing with
`NoClassDefFoundError` exception

```
20/11/17 15:26:56 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/cbor/CBORFactory
    at com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkJsonProtocolFactory.getSdkFactory(SdkJsonProtocolFactory.java:123)
    at com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkJsonProtocolFactory.createGenerator(SdkJsonProtocolFactory.java:54)
    at com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkJsonProtocolFactory.createGenerator(SdkJsonProtocolFactory.java:74)
    at com.amazonaws.protocol.json.SdkJsonProtocolFactory.createProtocolMarshaller(SdkJsonProtocolFactory.java:64)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.transform.DescribeStreamRequestProtocolMarshaller.marshall(DescribeStreamRequestProtocolMarshaller.java:52)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.executeDescribeStream(AmazonKinesisClient.java:861)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.describeStream(AmazonKinesisClient.java:846)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.describeStream(AmazonKinesisClient.java:887)
    at com.gartner.tn.datafeed.application.PositionStreamApplicationV4.getJavaDStream(PositionStreamApplicationV4.java:240)
```

Comment: how did this problem solve for you ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue and I solved it by removing the dependence on CBOR from Kinesis.  I am not sure if that is an option for you but it worked for me.

There are a few ways to do this but, for when running in local mode, I put the following code at the beginning of the main class in my streaming spark application;

```
System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.AWS_CBOR_DISABLE_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");
```

When running in cluster mode start your spark submit as follows;

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster \
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.disableCbor=true' \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions='-Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.disableCbor=true'
```

When running in client mode on the cluster start like this;

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client \
--driver-java-options '-Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.disableCbor=true' \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions='-Dcom.amazonaws.sdk.disableCbor=true'
```

This question led me to the answer; [Getting an AmazonKinesisException Status Code: 502 when using LocalStack from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56520354/getting-an-amazonkinesisexception-status-code-502-when-using-localstack-from-ja)

Comment: for me...at cluster mode, it doesn't honor the params. still gives this error.