# cannot read kinesis stream with flink, getting SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Current token (VALUE_STRING)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-agent

I am trying to read kinesis (actually running a local mocking with [kinesa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kinesalite)) from flink. This is my consumer configuration :

```
val consumerConfig = new Properties()
  consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_REGION, "us-east-1")
  consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, "x")
  consumerConfig.put(AWSConfigConstants.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, "x")
  consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfigConstants.STREAM_INITIAL_POSITION, "LATEST")

val kinesis =
   env.addSource(new FlinkKinesisConsumer[String](
     inputStreamName, new SimpleStringSchema(), consumerConfig))
     .print()
```

but when placing a record on the stream :

```
 aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4567 kinesis put-record --data "hello" --partition-key 0 --stream-name ExampleInputStream
```

i am getting the following error:

```
org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Current token (VALUE_STRING) not VALUE_EMBEDDED_OBJECT, can not access as binary
 at [Source: (org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.event.ResponseProgressInputStream); line: -1, column: 304]
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1201)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1147)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:796)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:764)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:698)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:680)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:544)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:524)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.doInvoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2809)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2776)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.invoke(AmazonKinesisClient.java:2765)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.executeGetRecords(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1292)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.AmazonKinesisClient.getRecords(AmazonKinesisClient.java:1263)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.proxy.KinesisProxy.getRecords(KinesisProxy.java:247)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.ShardConsumer.getRecords(ShardConsumer.java:401)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kinesis.internals.ShardConsumer.run(ShardConsumer.java:244)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Current token (VALUE_STRING) not VALUE_EMBEDDED_OBJECT, can not access as binary
 at [Source: (org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.event.ResponseProgressInputStream); line: -1, column: 304]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:712)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.cbor.CBORParser.getBinaryValue(CBORParser.java:1660)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.getBinaryValue(JsonParser.java:1484)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeCborUnmarshallers$ByteBufferCborUnmarshaller.unmarshall(SimpleTypeCborUnmarshallers.java:198)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.transform.SimpleTypeCborUnmarshallers$ByteBufferCborUnmarshaller.unmarshall(SimpleTypeCborUnmarshallers.java:196)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.transform.RecordJsonUnmarshaller.unmarshall(RecordJsonUnmarshaller.java:61)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.transform.RecordJsonUnmarshaller.unmarshall(RecordJsonUnmarshaller.java:29)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.transform.ListUnmarshaller.unmarshallJsonToList(ListUnmarshaller.java:92)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.transform.ListUnmarshaller.unmarshall(ListUnmarshaller.java:46)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.transform.GetRecordsResultJsonUnmarshaller.unmarshall(GetRecordsResultJsonUnmarshaller.java:53)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.model.transform.GetRecordsResultJsonUnmarshaller.unmarshall(GetRecordsResultJsonUnmarshaller.java:29)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.JsonResponseHandler.handle(JsonResponseHandler.java:118)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.JsonResponseHandler.handle(JsonResponseHandler.java:43)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.response.AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.handle(AwsResponseHandlerAdapter.java:69)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1714)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleSuccessResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1434)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1356)
    at org.apache.flink.kinesis.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1139)
    ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case i added this system properties :

```
System.setProperty(com.amazonaws.SDKGlobalConfiguration.AWS_CBOR_DISABLE_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true")
  System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.AWS_CBOR_DISABLE_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true")
  System.setProperty(SdkSystemSetting.CBOR_ENABLED.property(), "false")
```

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace it looks like Flink kinesis expects Cbor while your record is writting as a simple string.

It seems like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56520354/getting-an-amazonkinesisexception-status-code-502-when-using-localstack-from-ja) contains some hints on how to align your local setup with the consumer side.